# Get wall time from dataflow for a particular stage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-dataflow, wall-time

I am using **projects.jobs.getMetrics** to get all the job metric data from dataflow job. But wall time for a particular stage is not available in the response.

How to get wall time for a stage from a dataflow job?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [stages.getExecutionDetails](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs.stages/getExecutionDetails). Specifically, `startTime` and `endTime`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @chamikara, i tried this as well i think executiondetails for both job and stage is not available now its mentioned in the document that its experimental and may be removed.